# jquery detect the url to which something will get redirected

Tags: jquery

I have a window.onbeforeunload function, and I want to detect where I will get redirected to...

any ideas?

Markus

Comment: Is this from just anchors, or from form submits, etc?

Comment: from a flash (flex) plugin...

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It would be a security hole if you could.

If you want to find out where the user is going, then:

- It has to be somewhere *you* are sending them
- You need to handle it on the element which is sending them there

Linking to a redirect page on your own server is the simplest way to achieve this, buy be careful not to produce an open system that any spammer can relay people though to disguise their spam links.

Comment: This isn't necessarily true, a click handler on the exiting elements can give you this, when going forward anyway.

Comment: It is in the onbeforeunload function specified in the question. I was expanding my answer to deal with options beyond that while you wrote your comment.

Comment: The problem is, that The redirect comes for a flash plugin, which i cant detect with jquery...